Why pandas.merge_asof working with error in my case?
I'm trying to merge 2 tables with pandas.merge_asof.
First table administrators_system_with_schemes_sort:



salon_id
staff_id
date




872646
2715596
2024-10-02 00:00:00


872646
2715596
2024-10-03 00:00:00


872646
2715596
2024-10-06 00:00:00


872646
2715596
2024-10-07 00:00:00


872646
2715596
2024-10-10 00:00:00


872646
2715596
2024-10-11 00:00:00


872646
2715596
2024-10-14 00:00:00


872646
2715596
2024-10-15 00:00:00



Second table, bonus_and_penalty_for_staff_id_administrators_sort:



salon_id
staff_id
date
bonus
penalty




872646
2715596
2024-10-12 00:00:00
4070
0



My code:
astype_dict = {
    'salon_id': 'int64', 'staff_id': 'int64'
    , 'date': 'datetime64[ns]'
}

administrators_system_with_schemes['date'] = [pd.to_datetime(date).date() for date in administrators_system_with_schemes['date']]
bonus_and_penalty_for_staff_id_administrators['date'] = [pd.to_datetime(date).date() for date in bonus_and_penalty_for_staff_id_administrators['date']]

administrators_system_with_schemes_sort = (
    administrators_system_with_schemes.copy()
    .astype(astype_dict)
    .sort_values(by='date')
)

bonus_and_penalty_for_staff_id_administrators_sort = (
    bonus_and_penalty_for_staff_id_administrators.copy()
    .astype(astype_dict)
    .sort_values(by='date')
)

administrators_system_with_schemes_with_additional_bonus_penalty = (
    pd.merge_asof(
        left = administrators_system_with_schemes_sort
        , right = bonus_and_penalty_for_staff_id_administrators_sort
        , on = ['date']
        , by = ['salon_id', 'staff_id']
        , suffixes=['', '_y']
        , direction='nearest'
))

Result:
|   salon_id |   staff_id | date                |   bonus |   penalty |
|-----------:|-----------:|:--------------------|--------:|----------:|
|     872646 |    2715596 | 2024-10-02 00:00:00 |       0 |         0 |
|     872646 |    2715596 | 2024-10-03 00:00:00 |       0 |         0 |
|     872646 |    2715596 | 2024-10-06 00:00:00 |       0 |         0 |
|     872646 |    2715596 | 2024-10-07 00:00:00 |       0 |         0 |
|     872646 |    2715596 | 2024-10-10 00:00:00 |       0 |         0 |
|     872646 |    2715596 | 2024-10-11 00:00:00 |       0 |         0 |
|     872646 |    2715596 | 2024-10-14 00:00:00 |       0 |         0 |
|     872646 |    2715596 | 2024-10-15 00:00:00 |       0 |         0 |

Result is wrong, cause I got suitable value in tables.
I've already tries many way to change data types, but still have this mistake.
Any ideas, how to fix this problem?
Thanks.
Pandas ver. 2.1.4 (same error on ver.2.2.3).
Python ver. 3.11.7

I am not able to reproduce your output. Can you provide a complete reproducible example and your expected result?
Btw. is there some specific reason why you are using a list comprehension to transform the dtype of your date columns?

import pandas as pd


class DataMerger:
    def __init__(self, admins_df, bonuses_df):
        self.admins_df = admins_df
        self.bonuses_df = bonuses_df
        self.astype_dict = {
            'salon_id': 'int64',
            'staff_id': 'int64',
            'date': 'datetime64[ns]'
        }

    def preprocess_data(self):
        # Converting "date" columns to datetime format and ensuring the required data types
        self.admins_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.admins_df['date'])
        self.bonuses_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.bonuses_df['date'])

        # We apply typing and sorting
        self.admins_df = self.admins_df.astype(
            self.astype_dict).sort_values(by='date')
        self.bonuses_df = self.bonuses_df.astype(
            self.astype_dict).sort_values(by='date')

    def merge_data(self):
        # Using merge_asof to merge data
        merged_df = pd.merge_asof(
            left=self.admins_df,
            right=self.bonuses_df,
            on='date',
            by=['salon_id', 'staff_id'],
            suffixes=('', '_y'),
            direction='backward'  # Use backward to take into account the closest past values
        )

        # Fill NaN values ​​with zeros for bonuses and penalties
        merged_df[['bonus', 'penalty']] = merged_df[[
            'bonus', 'penalty']].fillna(0).astype(int)
        return merged_df


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Assume administrators_system_with_schemes and bonus_and_penalty_for_staff_id_administrators are your DataFrames
    administrators_system_with_schemes = pd.DataFrame({
        'salon_id': [872646] * 8,
        'staff_id': [2715596] * 8,
        'date': [
            '2024-10-02', '2024-10-03', '2024-10-06', '2024-10-07',
            '2024-10-10', '2024-10-11', '2024-10-14', '2024-10-15'
        ]
    })

    bonus_and_penalty_for_staff_id_administrators = pd.DataFrame({
        'salon_id': [872646],
        'staff_id': [2715596],
        'date': ['2024-10-12'],
        'bonus': [4070],
        'penalty': [0]
    })

    # Create an instance of the class and perform operations
    merger = DataMerger(administrators_system_with_schemes,
                        bonus_and_penalty_for_staff_id_administrators)
    merger.preprocess_data()
    print(merger.merge_data())


   salon_id  staff_id       date  bonus  penalty
0    872646   2715596 2024-10-02      0        0
1    872646   2715596 2024-10-03      0        0
2    872646   2715596 2024-10-06      0        0
3    872646   2715596 2024-10-07      0        0
4    872646   2715596 2024-10-10      0        0
5    872646   2715596 2024-10-11      0        0
6    872646   2715596 2024-10-14   4070        0
7    872646   2715596 2024-10-15   4070        0

pandas             2.2.3
python 3.12.7

Thanks. But after checking my data I realized, that I can't use standard rule as 'backward' or 'nearest' in my case. Cause then I use 'backward' rule, I can lose some data, then I got no suitable date. So then 'backward' rule fails, I need to select nearest date.
